# How to replace values with two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Assume, I have two HUGHE tables: one is for item id such as 10, 20, etc., and another one is item code. The goal is to replace all item id to its corresponding item code.

Table 1:

```
SELECT [customer]
      ,[item1]
      ,[item2]
      ,[item3]
      ,[item4]
FROM [StoreData].[dbo].[Customer]
```

| customer | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | NULL | 20 | 30 |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | 45 | 35 |
| 3 | 12 | NULL | 22 | 67 |
| 4 | 57 | 22 | 20 | NULL |

Table 2:

```
SELECT [item]
      ,[code]
FROM [StoreData].[dbo].[ItemCode]
```

| item | code |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1000 |
| 20 | 1000 |
| 30 | 1000 |
| 12 | 1500 |
| 22 | 1500 |
| 33 | 1500 |
| 35 | 2000 |
| 45 | 2000 |
| 57 | 2300 |
| 67 | 2300 |

Final table needs to be

| customer | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | NULL | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2 | NULL | NULL | 2000 | 2000 |
| 3 | 1500 | NULL | 1500 | 2300 |
| 4 | 2300 | 1500 | 10000 | NULL |

There are numerous items (> 1M rows). Thus it is no way to manually relabel these one by one. How can we do it automatically? Many Thanks

Comment: If you normalised your design, you would find this *far* easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why `JOIN`s exists:

```
SELECT 
    c.[customer],
    ic1.code Item1,
    ic2.code Item2,
    ic3.code Item3,
    ic4.code Item4
FROM [StoreData].[dbo].[Customer] c
LEFT JOIN [StoreData].[dbo].[ItemCode] ic1
    ON c.item1 = ic1.item
LEFT JOIN [StoreData].[dbo].[ItemCode] ic2
    ON c.item2 = ic2.item
LEFT JOIN [StoreData].[dbo].[ItemCode] ic3
    ON c.item3 = ic3.item
LEFT JOIN [StoreData].[dbo].[ItemCode] ic4
    ON c.item4 = ic4.item
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try aggratage condtion function `INNER JOIN` tables on `items`

```
SELECT t1.customer,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item1 = t2.item THEN t2.code END) item1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item2 = t2.item THEN t2.code END) item2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item3 = t2.item THEN t2.code END) item3 ,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.item4 = t2.item THEN t2.code END) item4
FROM [Customer] t1
INNER JOIN [ItemCode] t2
ON t2.item IN (t1.item1,t1.item2,t1.item3,t1.item4)
GROUP BY t1.customer
```

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b68407c2725c04b7057d21fd6293849)